# Split and concatenate a string in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I have the below line in by XML and also I need a hyperlink for the number. I want this output to be shown in HTML format.

```
<main>
<alph>a b 2,3</alph>
</main>
```

I want an XSLT that gives output as:

```
a b 2, a b 3
```

I have tried the below XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="alph">
  <xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(translate(
    normalize-space(current()),abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,''))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(.),$link)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tex">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($link,',')">
      <xsl:variable name="new">
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($link,',')"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($new,$tex)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains($link,'-')">
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($link,'-')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

But it is giving me output as:

```
a b 2 3a b 2,3
```

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing that you are using XSLT 2.0?

Comment: yes friend i'm using xslt 2.0. could you please edit or provide me a solution on how to do this. please

Comment: can you please let me know how to do it in XSLT1.0 thanks

Comment: The expression that you wrote is always going to be like that, or you can have more commas, e.g. a b 1,4,5,6 so the output should be a b 1, ab 4, a b 5, a b 6. Also how many elements can be present before the comma separated list? Could you define precisely the structure of the expression in a general way?

Comment: there would be only 1 element before comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have is with the variable **link**

```
<xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(translate(
     normalize-space(current()),abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,''))"/>
```

It looks like you are trying removing all alphabetic characters from the string, so that you are left with just **2,3**. However, for this to work the **abc...xyz** needs to be enclosed in apostrophes, otherwise it will be looking for an element named **abc...xyz**. Having said that, you say you are using XSLT2.0, so you can make use of the **replace** function here, which takes a regular expression as a parameter

```
<xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(replace(current(),'[a-z]',''))"/>
```

Next, you can get the text before this **link**, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="text" select="normalize-space(substring-before(current(), $link))"/>
```

This will give you your **a b**

Finally, you can use the **tokenize** function to split up the **2,3**. In your XSLT you seem to be looking for hyphens too, but the tokenize function also uses regular expressions, so this is not a problem. What you can do is just tokenize the string, and re-join it using the **text** variable as a separator

```
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($text, ' ')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($link,',|-')" separator="{concat(', ', $text, ' ')}"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:template match="alph">
      <xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(replace(current(),'[a-z]',''))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="text" select="normalize-space(substring-before(current(), $link))"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($text, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($link,',|-')" separator="{concat(', ', $text, ' ')}"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your XML, the following is output

```
a b 2, a b 3
```